# "Out of memory" error for an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am capturing images via my camera Canon SX - 120 IS. But when I try to process these images in Matlab, "out of memory" error is displayed. The dimension of my image is 2736x3648x3 uint8 type. The size is 1.05 MB. How to overcome this problem? Is it due to the image size or image dimensions? Is there any matlab function to reduce the size of the image keeping quality intact?

Comment: There are a lot of questions in your post. Consider asking multiple questions instead. Also, when getting "out of memory" issues, it is vital to post information about your operating system, and hardware. In addition, your question is vague: how do you process the image in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of each image in memory when you read it into matlab matrix will be

```
2736x3648x3 bites = 29942784 bites ~ 30 MB
```

Sometimes for processing the image has to be converted from `uint8` to `double`, in this case the size will be even larger at 8*30 = 240 MB.
If you have an array of these images (or do extensive processing) you can run out of memory. You can reduce the size of an image by using `imresize` function but the image quality will be lost.

The images that are stored in files are probably compressed (that's why I think it only takes 1.05 MB on disk). Consider processing images in batches by reading fewer number of images to memory at a time.

Comment: I am working with only 1 image at a time. imresize is fine. Thanks.